# Batch, Renaming a file when first characters match

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I'm currently trying to create a batch, which looks for a file starting with "CRM_DEB"(Complete name would be CRM_DEB_20160520 for example) and renaming it into just "CRM_DEB" my current failed attempt is this:

```
if "%filename:~0,7%"=="CRM_DEB" ren "CRM_DEB"
```

I'm a beginner in batch/scripting and if anyone knows how to make this work, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What is the result of "my current failed attempt"? Please be specific as what you experienced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only one file, you could do it like this:

```
 ren CRM_DEB* CRM_DEB
```